# Storing Multiple Selections in sectioned UITableView

Tags: iphone, arrays, uitableview, selection

I have a list of people in a UITableView, sectioned by the first letter of the persons name.

I want this list to allow MULTIPLE selections (imagine 100 people, in a list, sectioned by name, with a check box next to each name).

No problem with the UI - all sorted.

Its how to STORE the selections?

I need way to store and retrieve the selections (simple BOOL values) from some sort of array, by using the indexPath to find them.

Before using sections, it was easy - just an NSMutableArray, and retrieve by indexPath.row. But with sections I have to find by BOTH section AND row. Multidimensional arrays don't seem to go well with Objective C, though a multidimensional c array was suggested in one post somewhere.

I could save to the database - but thats a lot of save and retrieves as you scroll up and down a table checking and unchecking tickboxes.... and I dont need the data to persist in the DB anyway - going to then create records with pointers to the selected records.

Surely I am not the first person to reach this dilemma.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you add a selected property to your Person (or whatever) object, from which the cells are built? Then when you build the cell using a Person, just add or not add the checkbox. Or do you need something else?

Comment: As I said in the post, I don't want to store the selected property in the core data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd still be interested to hear ideas - but  after trawling the interwebs for hours (until 3am!) and not coming up with a solution, I decided to use an NSDictionary, constructing the key from the indexPath row and section thus:

```
 - (void) setSelected:(NSMutableDictionary*)dict forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath withValue:(BOOL)selected{

            NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell-%i-%i", (int)indexPath.section, (int)indexPath.row];

            [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:selected] forKey:cellIdentifier];

 }

- (BOOL) getSelected:(NSMutableDictionary*)dict forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell-%i-%i", (int)indexPath.section, (int)indexPath.row];
    BOOL selected=[[dict objectForKey:cellIdentifier]  boolValue];

    return selected;

}
- (BOOL) toggleSelected:(NSMutableDictionary*)dict forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell-%i-%i", (int)indexPath.section, (int)indexPath.row];

    BOOL selected=[[dict objectForKey:cellIdentifier]  boolValue];
    selected=!selected;

    [self setSelected:dict forIndexPath:indexPath withValue:selected];

    return selected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mutable array to store persons or indexes of persons that are selected. This will go inside your didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
UITableViewCell *currentCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (currentCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    currentCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    //save/delete your person or index in/from a global mutable array
}
```

And in your cellForRowATIndexPath you could set the accessory based on whats in the array and whats not. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Xs2Bush thanks - but what sort of index do you use to store the BOOL (or indexPath) in a mutable array, that would allow you to retrieve it at cellForRowAtIndexPath? I could not find any way to convert an indexPath into an index for a mutable array.... if you know how, please post! (You're right - I could store the entire object in an array - but pretty heavy given all I want is a BOOL)

Comment: if ur using an array for ur data, you can initialize a mutable array of the same size and set all to false. Then after a cell is selected, set the object at that index to true, using something like [selectionArray setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] atIndex:indexPath.row]. Then in cell for row at indexpath just check if the value is true for [[selectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue].

Comment: That would work for a table with only one section. But this table has multiple sections - so you need to index the data by BOTH row AND section. The data also comes from a core data FRC. Again, I think I pointed this out in the initial post.

Comment: If this doesnt change ur algorithm a whole lot, you could retrieve the data from Fetched results controller in an array of arrays. The index of subarray would be indexPath.section and index of person would be indexPath.row. I think retrieving the data into an array from frc would be better implementation than accessing ur frc in cellForRowAtIndexPath while using reusable cells.

Comment: just crossed my mind, even if you dont copy ur data into arrays. You must know the number of sections and rows of the table. Make an array of <num of sections> arrays and each array would have <num of rows in each section> elements. Now you can use them like we discussed before.